# Getting the starting address of the start of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct foo {
     long a;
     float d;
     void *some_ptr;
}

struct foo *start_address(void *some_other_ptr) {
    return ((struct test *)((char *) linkfield_ptr //Don't know what to do here);
}

int main() {
     struct foo fum;
     struct foo *foo_ptr;

     foo_ptr = start_address(&fum.some_ptr);
}
```

foo_ptr needs to be the starting address of the struct so basically the start_address method has to return that. I have been bashing my head against this problem for an hour or so as i am not allowed to use any macros or external libraries for find the answer. An answer to this as well as an explanation of how they got the answer from pointer gurus would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the starting address of fum = address of fum = &fum?

Comment: C11 draft standard `6.3.2.3 Pointers, Section 7 [...]When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.`.

Comment: The element in the struct has to be used in order to derive the return statement for the start_address method, hence the start_address(&fum.some_ptr) call. @EOF - has to be C90 :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `void* some_ptr` is the first field of the struct then it's trivially the same address.

Otherwise a generic solution would be similar to the implementation of `offsetof`, something like:

```
unsigned int offset = &((struct foo*)0)->some_ptr;
```

[complete example](http://ideone.com/edE0R3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct foo
{
    int padding1;
    unsigned char padding3;
    void* ptr;
    int padding2;
};

struct foo* start_address(void* ptr)
{
    uintptr_t offset = (uintptr_t)&((struct foo*)0)->ptr;
    return (struct foo*)(ptr - offset);
}

int main(void) {
    struct foo test;
    printf("%p == %p\n", &test, start_address(&test.ptr));
    return 0;
}
```

This is easy to think about, you cast address `0` to be considered the addres of a `struct foo*`, then if you try to obtain address of any field of that struct you get the offset (since you were starting from `0`).

Comment: Its not the first field, i forgot to add the other elements. Adding em now.

Comment: So should start_address return &((struct foo*) 0) -> some_ptr; ? Can the *some_other_ptr variable be used somehow to get the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks for the complete example Jack. Now i understand what you meant. Really don't believe i deserved a -1 for asking this but oh well.

Comment: This: `&((struct foo*)0)->some_ptr;` is dereferencing a NULL pointer.  How is this not undefined behavior?

Comment: @dbush: You are not dereferencing the value, you are asking for a field of an address which doesn't constitute a dereference, there is no code that is trying to inspect the address itself, just querying for the offset of a field. It's like wondering why `void* ptr = 0 + 5` is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jack: No exception in relation to its use in direct conjunction with `&` is made for `->` the way it is for `*` or `[]`.

Comment: @EOF: It's more a philosophical point of view than a realistic point of view. This same issue has been discussed before even here on SO. Undefined behavior is implementation specific in the end, and in this circumstance most compilers align on the same behavior (the offsetof macro includes this too). So what's the point? If the standard library includes this implementation for the macro then is it to be considered undefined behavior or not? At the same time, you are not effectively accessing a value, since you are merely doing pointer arithmetics.